# What is the minimum height among probability densities having mean 0 and variance 1?

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization

It seems to me that the U($-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}$) density provides this minimum, with height $1/(2\sqrt{3})$. Is this true? And if so, how does the proof look?

Comment: how do you define the height of a probability distribution?

Comment: The proof would be in two steps.  First show that uniform over an interval gives minimum height and then calculate what the interval would be.

Comment: I mean height to be $\max_x p(x)$.

Comment: Herb, it's the first step that I don't see how to do.  The second step is trivial by the moment constraint. Clues?